# show table view data grouped by on iphone

Tags: iphone

i am pulling data from xml so is that possible to show them group by??

i have no plsit right now i am showing data just as simple so now i want group by what should be the approach/concept??

i did something like this but no luck

**d**o i need to do some sorting?? like using NSSortDescriptor??****

if yes then where in **viewdidload** or in **cellforrowatindxpath?**?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //UITableView *tableView;
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    **Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];**
```

/// how to arrange them in group by??

i tried this

```
NSString *keys =aBook.name;
NSMutableDictionary *dicta = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dicta setObject:keys forKey:@"message"];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor = 
    [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
      initWithKey:@"message" ascending:YES] 
     autorelease];
```

but i cant display them in alphabetical order :(

```
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are these things called table sections. Perhaps you should look into them and the TableViewSuite samples.

Comment: thanks but i have no idea how to proceed , should i create dic and then display??  where should i  add elements to dic ??can you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I create a NSDictionary where each entry has a key containing the sectionName and the value is a list of anything used to fill the cell. If you have that :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return [[data allkeys] count]; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  NSString* key = [[data allkeys] objectAtIndex:section];
  return [[data objectForKey:key] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [[data allkeys] objectAtIndex:section]; //If key is NSString* of course
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ...//classical code the retrieve a valid cell
  NSString* key = [[data allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSObject* obj = [[data objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  ...//Setup the cell with obj properties.
}
```

You can optimize that code a lot but it works fine for small amount of data.

if you want any of the group or value to be sorted, you can use NSSortDescriptors like this for exemple (sort an array of string)

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortAsc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
[anyArrayOfNSString sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortAsc]];        
[sortAsc release];
```

of course I advice you to avoid sorting every time you need a value.  Do the sort once when the data becomes available.

Comment: @arutema : see post modification above.

Comment: ok 1 doubt .. what is issueNumbers?? (an array) and initWithKey: should be nil or my key??  see my modified code above

Comment: i am just confused where to sort , should i sort when i am parsing xml or when ???

Comment: Of course the best moment to arrange your NSArray's is when you parse your xml or just after.  Be aware that a dictionary is never sorted but that you can keep a sorted Array of its key.

Comment: Il you arrays is an array of NSString, sort key must be null ! The key is used to provide a "path" to the "property" to use when comparing elements.